# How to remove border of a ActionContent & NavigationContent on ActionBar

Tags: ios, apache-flex, android-actionbar

When I add navigationContent and actionContent on the actionBar in flex mobile application, I get visible border, I need to know how to remove it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should make your own ActionBarButtonSkin and override this method:

```
override protected function get border():DisplayObject
    {
        // TODO Auto Generated method stub
        var border:DisplayObject = super.border;
        border.alpha = 0;
        return border;
    }
```